# transformation of an equation (Binomial coefficient)

Tags: binomial-coefficients, transformation

Good afternoon

I don't understand this transformation. Can you please help me?

Greetings

Ava

$\begin{align}{n \choose k}&=\frac{n}{1}\cdot\frac{n-1}{2}\cdots\frac{n-(k-1)}{k}\\&=\frac{n\cdot (n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}\end{align}$

Comment: the above part is just a multiplication $n-(k-1)=n-1\cdot(k-1)=n-k+1$... The below part is just the definition of $k!$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site using MathJax.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Is it possible to remove the central  = between lines by Latex?

Comment: @Narasimham  Somebody left an extra equals sign after the aligned equations, producing the central equals sign you noticed.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)(n-k)!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Cancel out the$ (n-k)!$ and you're done.

Comment: Good evening
But I don't understand how to get from n factorial to this equation in the numerator.
greetings
ava

Comment: Good evening @Ava .. Well imagine $k=3$ and $n=5$.. couldn't you write $5!$ as $5.4.3.2!$ where $2!=(n-k)!$?

Comment: But n factorial should be n(n-1)(n-2).... But why n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)(n-k)factorial

Comment: Mathematically $n(n-1)(n-2)....(2)(1) = n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)(n-k)!$